# Testing TypeScript and AngularJS in Visual Studio with Jasmine and Chutzpah - can't find variable: angular

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, typescript, chutzpah

I'm trying to test my TypeScript and AngularJS code with Jasmine in Visual Studio Chutzpah. Test is running correctly in karma, but I realy like Chutzpah's UI.

My `controllerSpecs.ts`:

```
/// <chutzpah_reference path="../Scripts/angular.js" />
/// <chutzpah_reference path="../Scripts/angular-mocks.js" />
/// <chutzpah_reference path="../Scripts/angular-route.js" />
/// <chutzpah_reference path="../Scripts/angular-resource.js" />
/// <chutzpah_reference path="../Scripts/angular-local-storage.js" />
/// <chutzpah_reference path="../Controllers/MenuController.js" />
/// <chutzpah_reference path="../App/app.js" />
/// <chutzpah_reference path="../references.js" />
/// <reference path="../references.ts" />

describe('Controller Specs', () => {

describe('Menu Controller Specs', () => {
    var menuCtrl, scope;

    beforeEach(angular.mock.module('typewritingApp'));

    beforeEach(() => inject(($rootScope) => {

        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        menuCtrl = new App.MenuCtrl(scope);
    }));

    it('should be true', () => {
        expect(true).toBe(true);
    });
});

});
```

My `app.ts`:

```
module App {
var typewritingapp: ng.IModule = angular.module("typewritingApp", [])
    .controller("MenuCtrl", ["$scope", MenuCtrl])
}
```

My `MenuController.ts`:

```
module App {

export class MenuCtrl {
    constructor($scope: any) {
        $scope.pageTitle = "Menu";
    }
}
}
```

If I change the `angular.mock.module` part to `module` in the test (and I also need to modify the angular-mocks.d.ts to declare module) I receive the same error but it doesn't find variable: module.

Comment: Are you using a chutzpah.json file and is it referencing a similar set of files as your karma.conf?

Comment: Ah thanks. I had a wrong karma config file and I've forgot to update chutzpah.json... Thanks a lot.

Comment: @bucicimaci you should post an answer for your won question, so this question can be closed and it to help others in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a wrong karma config file and after it has started to work I forgot to update chutzpah.json so it was my fault. Thanks for the help @MatthewManela